# Understanding Eager Loading

Tags: performance, eager-loading

I am trying to get to grips with Eager Loading. I have the following code:

```
{% for article in entry.relatedArticles %}
<div class="c-card // l-card--third">
    <a href="{{ article.url }}">
        <img src="{{ article.bannerImage.first().getUrl('cardImage') }}" alt="{{ article.title }}" class="c-card__img">
        <div class="c-card__bar // js_fitcontent">
            {% set array = article.title|split(' ', 2) %}
            <p class="c-card__title"><strong>{{ attribute(array, 0) }}</strong> {{ attribute(array, 1) }}</p>
            <p class="c-card__msg // js-fittext">Posted on {{ helpers.date_formatted(entry.postDate) }}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="c-card__over">
            <div class="c-card__over-content">
                <div class="animate">
                    <p class="c-card__title"><strong>Related</strong> Article</p>
                    <p class="c-card__msg  // half-margin-bottom">
                        <strong>{{ article.title }}</strong><br />
                        <time datetime="{{ entry.postDate|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}" class="date">
                            <svg role="img" class="icon // icon-date" title="Date Icon">
                                <use xlink:href="/assets/img/icons.svg#icon-date"></use>
                            </svg>{{ helpers.date_formatted(entry.postDate) }}
                        </time>
                    </p>
                    <p class="btn // btn--sub">Read Article</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Looking on the console this combined with the other page requests totals 76 requests. I thought I perhaps should add some eager loading 9at least tot he image transform) So I tried the following:

```
{% for article in entry.relatedArticles.withTransforms('cardImage') %}
<div class="c-card // l-card--third">
    <a href="{{ article.url }}">
        <img src="{{ article.bannerImage.first().getUrl('cardImage') }}" alt="{{ article.title }}" class="c-card__img">
        <div class="c-card__bar // js_fitcontent">
            {% set array = article.title|split(' ', 2) %}
            <p class="c-card__title"><strong>{{ attribute(array, 0) }}</strong> {{ attribute(array, 1) }}</p>
            <p class="c-card__msg // js-fittext">Posted on {{ helpers.date_formatted(entry.postDate) }}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="c-card__over">
            <div class="c-card__over-content">
                <div class="animate">
                    <p class="c-card__title"><strong>Related</strong> Article</p>
                    <p class="c-card__msg  // half-margin-bottom">
                        <strong>{{ article.title }}</strong><br />
                        <time datetime="{{ entry.postDate|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}" class="date">
                            <svg role="img" class="icon // icon-date" title="Date Icon">
                                <use xlink:href="/assets/img/icons.svg#icon-date"></use>
                            </svg>{{ helpers.date_formatted(entry.postDate) }}
                        </time>
                    </p>
                    <p class="btn // btn--sub">Read Article</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

However, this also still results in 76 requests.

So my question is this; Have I misunderstood when I need to use Eager Loading? or is my code incorrect and thus eager loading isn't actually taking place?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is a bit off.

The `withTransforms` parameter is an *Asset criteria*, meaning it is only relevant when you're pulling Assets. Appending it to `entry.relatedArticles` (an Entries field, returning an ElementCriteriaModel) like you're currently attempting does nothing, but this does:

```
{% set assets = entry.someAssetsField.find({
    withTransforms: ['someTransform', 'someOtherTransform']
}) %}
```

This means your current code should probably be refactored to look something like this (simplified):

```
{% for article in entry.relatedArticles %}
    ...
    {% set bannerImage = article.bannerImage.find({
        withTransforms: ['cardImage']
    })[0] ?? null %}
    {% if bannerImage %}
        <img src="{{ bannerImage.getUrl('cardImage') }}" />
    {% endif %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Assuming there's not a *ton* of `relatedArticles` entries, and considering the fact that there's only one image per entry, the above might not make a huge impact on your performance. To take things a step further, you might consider eager loading the actual Asset field(s) as well as their transforms. There's a couple of ways to do this – you could use the same approach as above, adding the eager loading criteria to the Entries field `relatedArticles`:

```
{% set relatedArticles = entry.relatedArticles.find({
  with: [
      ['bannerImage', {
          withTransforms: ['cardImage']
      }]
  ]
}) %}
{% for article in relatedArticles %}
    ...
    {% set bannerImage = article.bannerImage[0] ?? null %}
    {% if bannerImage %}
        <img src="{{ bannerImage.getUrl('cardImage') }}" />
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

...or you could use a more "traditional" eager loading approach, using `craft.entries` and [the `relatedTo` parameter](https://craftcms.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param):

```
{% for article in craft.entries({
    relatedTo: {
      sourceElement: entry,
      field: 'relatedArticles'
    },
    with: [
        ['bannerImage', {
            withTransforms: ['cardImage']
        }]
    ]
}) %}
    ...
    {% set bannerImage = article.bannerImage[0] ?? null %}
    {% if bannerImage %}
        <img src="{{ bannerImage.getUrl('cardImage') }}" />
    {% endif %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

With the above, assuming there's a fair amount of entries involved you'll probably see a decrease in the number of queries executed.

If you want to learn more about eager loading, I recommend taking a look at [the official docs on the subject](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/eager-loading-elements).

Comment: Thanks for this Mats. Is there a general guide as to when you should really use Eager loading? I am not seeing much improvement. Perhaps my implementation isn't 100%. I currently have 77 queries for the whole page. This includes a matrix block, 4 related product, 3 related articles (cards), and three related articles (titles and dates).

Comment: The general rule is "whenever you need to avoid the [N+1 query problem](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-n-1-problem)". 77 queries isn't actually a huge number and eager loading isn't a silver bullet, but it can be very effective. Without seeing your complete template its impossible to say if eager loading will make a big difference in your particular case, but if the number of queries doesn't go down at all its likely that your implementation is still off.

Comment: For more info, see [the official docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/eager-loading-elements) or [Straight Up Craft](https://straightupcraft.com/articles/examples-of-eager-loading-elements-in-twig-and-php). There's probably more resources out there, and you could also tune into [the official Slack channel](https://craftcms.com/community?utm_campaign=Craft%2BLink%2BList&amp;utm_medium=web&amp;utm_source=Craft_Link_List_5) to discuss the subject further and/or get more help.

Comment: Thanks. I will have another look through my code as to why this wasn't working correctly. I tried on Slack but didn't get much input. The first suggestion in your answer I was getting errors, the second more comprehensive approach, worked (no errors) but I can't recall how effective it was. I am only calling three related cards. So might not impact really.
I will take another look. Thanks.

Comment: Let's say you have a template with 4 separate queries (e.g. `craft.entries` or `craft.categories` etc), where each query returns only a small number of elements (e.g. 5 entries, 3 categories) with relational data; you're not going to see a huge improvement with eager loading. Eager loading is really only very effective when a single query results in large number of additional queries (e.g. a query that returns a set of 100 entries, each with 3 different relational fields – that would amount to _301 queries_ in total using lazy loading, but could be reduced to 1 query with eager loading).

Comment: Also, the first example in my answer was basically lifted straight from the [docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/eager-loading-elements#eager-loading-image-transform-indexes) – what was the error?

Comment: The error is Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "bannerImage".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48283/discussion-between-terry-upton-and-mats-mikkel-rummelhoff).

Comment: Regarding the error, there was a typo in the docs where I lifted the example from. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Thanks for this Mats. Is there a general guide as to when you should really use Eager loading? I am not seeing much improvement

The article [Speed up your Craft CMS Templates with Eager Loading](https://nystudio107.com/blog/speed-up-your-craft-cms-templates-with-eager-loading) I wrote hopefully gives you the "general guide" you asked for.